# Reducing the file size of camera captured image in cn1

Tags: codenameone

I need to upload camera captured image to the server, but it should be less than 500 KB. In case, if it is greater than 500 KB, it needs to be reduced to the size less than 500 KB.

How can I do it? Is this feature available in cn1? Thankyou...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since images are compressed you can't determine the size of the image in KB as a picture of object X might be larger than a picture of object Y.

You only have control over the dimensions of the image. You have two options:

- Determine arbitrary width/height dimensions that would always fall under the 500kb quota in which case you can use the version of capture that accepts width and height
- Write a special heuristic that checks the image size and tries to guess a reasonable width/height then scales the image down using `ImageIO` until it finds the optimal size

Since option 2 is complex and slow I'd recommend option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Jpeg format has a quality parameter, it's that available through some option?